# How to hide or show elements in the view according to the screen size using rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

Here's a part of the code of my signin form :

```
    <div class="row">

        <div class="small-10 medium-8 large-6 small-centered columns">

            <div class="row collapse animated slideInLeft">

                <div class="hide-for-small-only medium-4 large-4 large-centered columns ">
                  <%= f.label :email, 'Email', class: "prefix signlbl email" %>
                </div>

                <div class="hide-for-small-only small-12 medium-8 large-8 columns">
                  <%= f.text_field :email, class: "input" %>
                </div>
                <div class="show-for-small-only small-12 medium-8 large-8 columns">
                  <%= f.text_field :email, class: "input smallmail", autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email" %>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>          

    </div>
```

I have used Zurb foundation to show and hide the email form according to the screen size. When the screen is smaller, a different input field is shown with an additional class 'smallmail' (so i can style the mobile version differently) and a placeholder because in the mobile version I hide the label. The placeholder is not required to the full version of the site.

This works but there's a problem. The form have two input fields with email and the Rails application gets confused. The form doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: why do you actually need the two email fields? It seems to me that you should let the css take care of the responsiveness. The style varies with the screensize, but the form stays the same. I think that you need two ways to style the email input, rather than two separate email fields. (edit: rails4guides said it better :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want multiple input fields for email? If all you want is different styling, you are going in the wrong direction. If you want to style your mobile version differently you can use media-queries: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html. Now you can add additional css for small screens.

Comment: Is it possible to add the placeholder like that?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used media queries to style the placeholder white on full screen so they are invisible!